# How to create variadic function? (Can take any number of arguments)

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I was wondering if there is a similar way to do this (C# definition) in Objective-C:

```
public void MyWorkingMethod (string Argument1, params int numbers)
```

It can be called like `MyWorkingMethod("a")` or `MyWorkingMethod("b", 1, 2, 3)`.

I'm trying to implement the `string.Format` as C# does in Objective-c.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that there is already a [stringWithFormat](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) method that is very similar to string.Format found in the .NET Framework. That said, you can definitely have a variable number of arguments in an Objective-C method. See [this link](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1405/_index.html) for details.

Comment: yes i know about the stringWithFormat the thing about the format of .Net is that i can do this: string.Format("I want to {0} this string. it {1} very important to me to be able to {0} strings, because it {1}","format","is") and i would get as result the {0}'s replaced by the ToString() result of parameter 1, and the {1}'s replaced by parameter 2...

Answer (score 0):

What exactly `string.Format` does? If you need a function, declare and define it as you'd do in C (including variadic cases):

```
void MyWorkingMethod (NSString *string, int numbers)
```

If it's related to formatting a string, have you checked NSString's `stringWithFormat:?` What about libc `sprintf`?

Answer (score -1):

It should be something like

```
 - (void) MyWorkingMethod : ( NSString * ) Argument1 secondInput:(NSArray *) numbers {
 }
```

And you will call the function with

```
[self MyWorkingMethod:@"Hello World" secondInput:numbers];
```

Comment: i don't want a defined number of parameters... arrays can grow but i would still have to supply a array...